# How do I improve my Chess rating

Tags: rating, online-chess, computer-chess

Its been almost three and a half years since I am playing chess online on chess.com. But I never crossed my Chess rating above 1500 on chess.com. And I think that three years is enough for anyone to become an advanced player in chess. I spent almost one and half an hour daily on chess.com and I play mostly 3 minutes game. What should I do to improve my rating?